# Are Soft and Bahdanau attentions different?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, attention-mechanism

I have been working on a Image Captioning model. And read many articles accomplishing it. Some used both attentions interchangably while some did not. And the formulaes differed too. So, I would like to know if Soft Attention and Bahdanau Attention are any different?

Comment: Normally, "soft" attention is the opposite of "hard" attention. Soft means that the weights are in $[0, 1]$, while in hard attention, weights are either 0 or 1. Therefore, Bahdanau attention is just a type of soft attention. Can you add a reference of what you understand for "soft attention"?

Comment: thanks for the reply @noe, can you please add a reference that shows that Bahdanau is a type/variation of soft?

Comment: articles that i had referenced for soft attention: 1) https://jhui.github.io/2017/03/15/Soft-and-hard-attention/ 2) https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/image-captioning-with-attention-part-1-e8a5f783f6d3 3) https://medium.com/swlh/image-captioning-using-attention-mechanism-f3d7fc96eb0e

Comment: Articles (1) and (2) use the term "soft attention" in the same sense I mentioned before. Article (3) does not mention soft attention anywhere.

Comment: Article (2) also shows how the Bahdanau attention is soft.

Comment: oh ok. thanks. Will you please be able to share me any reference(research paper preferably) which shows that bahdanau is a variation of soft attention.